# Change img src value on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of jQuery that changes the value of a hidden field when the user form is saved, as below:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $("#avatar-val").val($(".avatar-view>img").prop('src'));
});
```

I also need it to work in reverse (kind of). So that when the user goes back to there user page, it will take the value of whats in the hidden field and put it into the `img` src of the default avatar image (in the div `avatar-view`, `picture.jpg`)

I tried add the below but I can't get it to work

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".avatar-view>img").src($("#avatar-val").prop('src'));
});
```

```html
<div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block avatar-save">
        Change Avatar
    </button> 
    <img src="/scripts/cropper/img/picture.jpg" alt="Avatar" >
</div> 

<input name="avatar" value="../cropper/img/20150729105134.png" id="avatar-val" type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.attr(attributename, value)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead of <strike>src()</strike>

```
$(".avatar-view > img").attr('src' ,$("#avatar-val").val());
```

[**--Working DEMO--**](https://jsfiddle.net/bk2Lgrbt/)

Comment: Excellent. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3):

`.src()` doesn't exists in jQuery, You should use [`.prop(propertyName, value)`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) function

> Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.

And to read `input` value use `.val()` method.

*Use*

```
$(".avatar-view > img").prop('src', $("#avatar-val").val());
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".avatar-view > img").prop('src', $("#avatar-val").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="avatar-view" title="Change the avatar">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block avatar-save">
    Change Avatar
  </button>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7839089cd91dc5cc5eb1e0cdbf3312ed" alt="Avatar">
</div>

<input name="avatar" value="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1a7926d223f025242d8ec5b120cc3e68" id="avatar-val" type="hidden">
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it but that seems to strip out the imgsrc for some reason. Ends up like this: '<img src="" alt="Avatar">'

Comment: @Rob88991 Are you sure that the `src` property of `#avatar-val` has a value?

Comment: @ANVerona No sorry it only has a value, it tried changing it to     $(".avatar-view > img").prop('src', $("#avatar-val").prop('val'));     but that didnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

`<img src='images/sample.jpg' />`

if you want to change from page load then make html image tag to runat server

```
<img   id='myImage' runat='server' src='images/sample.jpg' />
```

and write bellow code on page load

```
myImage.src = 'image path here';
```